# Problem with importing polish stock data from stooq.com

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I got problem with importing stock data for Polish Stock from stooq.com.

```
import pandas_datareader.stooq
df = pandas_datareader.stooq.StooqDailyReader('PGE')
df = df.read()
df.head()
```

In result i get empty data frame.
This code work for example AMZN but for ticker of Polish stock no and for example for ^SPX don't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "pge.pl" instead of just "pge". On default it reads "pge.us". For all polish stocks you have to add a ".pl" suffix to a ticker.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Instead of pandas_datareader.stooq.StooqDailyReader('PGE') use pandas_datareader.stooq.StooqDailyReader('pge.pl')